# Remove the border of an input field, but leave the bottom

Tags: css

I have many input fields, but I only want for the bottom border to appear. I've already tried using

```
border-left: none;
border-width: 0;
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to post the complete code that will lead to the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove all borders except for the bottom one on all input fields using CSS. See the code snippet below.

```css
input {
  margin: 20px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom:0.5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"> <br />
<input type="text"> <br />
<input type="text">
```

Comment: If that doesn't help, you might have to create a more specific selector to overwrite previously set styles.

Comment: Yes, you're right